# Headcount per hour excel 2003

Tags: excel

I have 4 people. Each of them can work diffrent hours each day.
I need to know how many ppl is available each day every hour.

e.g. on Sunday between 7 and 11 there is only 1 person on shift, from 12 till 3pm are 2, then from 4pm will midnight is again only 1.
How can I do it?

Please see link to get more idea.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TmJF.gif

- RD means rest day

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)  **Otherwise** this may be a question more suited for SuperUser

Comment: I think I finally work this out but it is bit long way.

On another tab in colum A i put hours from 07:00 to 24:00 (A1 is 07:00, A2 is 08:00)

To work out start and end of shift i put code

    =IF(A2>'Shift Rota'!$C$3;1;0)
    =IF(A2>'Shift Rota'!$D$3;1;0)
IF sum of both is 1 it returns with Yes.

    =IF(B1+C1=1;"Yes";"No")

Then just simple count if Yes and return value in right place.

This is bit long way as I have to do it for each day separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you need to use the PIVOT tables, and for your requirement you need to understand it well.
understanding of such features can be gained by practice only.

Below is the Link to get started
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pivottable-reports-101-HA001034632.aspx

and also look at

http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/

I hope it would help you.